# SELECT and create new ID for unique ids having identical values on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

My table

```
 ID  Name    Addr   tDate
-------------------------------
| 1 | Aa  |  street |  20151231
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20130202
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20120101
| 3 | Aa  |  way    |  20150821
| 4 | Bb  |  street |  20150821 
| 7 | Xb  |  street |  20150821 
| 5 | Cc  |  way    |  20150821
| 5 | Cc  |  way    |  20150821
| 6 | Cc  |  no way |  20150821
```

Result 01

```
 ID  Name    Addr   | tDate
-------------------------------
| 1 | Aa  |  street |  20151231
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20130202
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20120101
```

Going to create a new `nID` 
It should be copied as is OR merged if Name and Addr are identical and selecting `ID` with newest `tDate`

Result 02

```
 ID  Name    Addr      tDate      nID
------------------------------------
| 1 | Aa  |  street |  20151231 | 1
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20120101 | 1    <-- nID != ID
| 2 | Aa  |  street |  20130202 | 1    <-- nID != ID
| 3 | Aa  |  way    |  20150821 | 3
| 4 | Bb  |  street |  20150821 | 4 
| 7 | Xb  |  street |  20150821 | 7 
| 5 | Cc  |  way    |  20150821 | 5
| 5 | Cc  |  way    |  20150821 | 5
| 6 | Cc  |  no way |  20150821 | 6
```

I've tried this. Not sure if it's correct.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT dr.*
                FROM MyTable dr
                inner join(
                    SELECT ID, Name, Addr
                    FROM MyTable
                    GROUP BY ID, Name, Addr
                ) ss on dr.Name = ss.Name and 
                        dr.Addr = ss.Addr and 
                        dr.ID <> ss.ID 
                order by Name
```

Comment: damn sorry.. Bb and Xb have different ID - Edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** : *Complete change after your addition of tDate, and need for two result sets*

Result Set 1:

```
SELECT
    id, Name, Addr, tDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Addr)   AS occurrences
    FROM
        MyTable
)
    AS parsed
WHERE
   occurrences > 1
```

Result Set 2:

```
SELECT
    *,
    FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Addr
                              ORDER BY tDate DESC
                               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)   AS nID
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    ID
```

Example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9285ae/9

Comment: You missed a `comma` after `select *`

Comment: For id 4 and 7, the nID is not what OP is asking for

Comment: @Madhivanan - On the original question it was, on the first edit you're right, but by the second edit this answer is right again.

Comment: Worked. But cannot use the result. This gives all rows, was going to check manually which ID to use, before insert update into another table.

Comment: Worked. But cannot use the result. This gives all rows. I meant to get result where there are only rows having same `Name` and `Addr`. Was going to check manually which `ID` to use, before inserting into another table and updating rest of `nID`'s. Now, best solution would be to select `ID` based on 4th column value `tDate`, formatted: YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Kaptah - So, what do you want, just the rows that are duplicates and have an nID that is different *(Just row 2 in your example)*?  Or all the rows in the group where any of the rows have a new nID *(Rows 1 and 2 in your example)*.  If you specifiy your desired output I can make it work for you.

Comment: Actually i need both. 1) One having all rows based on newest `tDate` 2) the other having only duplicate rows with new `nID` with biggest `tDate`

Comment: @Kaptah - Please could you update your question to Show what results you want to output given your example data?  Your original question says `please calculate nID for me using these rules` now you're asking not to do that, you want to do it manually?  Also you're now asking for two sets of results?  You also talk about a field `tDate`, but that isn't mentioned Anywhere in your question....  Your question is becoming vague and contradictory, sorry.  Once it's clear what you're doing, what you have, and what you want; then I'll help further.

Comment: Edited question. Thought i could manage it by first solving original query. But both results are needed.

Comment: @Kaptah - New solutions addeed.  In future, however, please could you open a new question rather than constantly making functional changes to an open question?

Comment: Sure, I'll post new next time.

Comment: The query doesn't seem to give new `nID`

Comment: @Kaptah - Result Set 2 does that, in your requested results you don't ask for a `nID` in Result Set 1.

Comment: Yeah, it gives but nID = ID on each row

Comment: @Kaptah - Apologies, seems that `LAST_VALUE()` is subtly different to `FIRST_VALUE()`.  Answer updated.

Comment: This does it. Great job @MatBailie. Thanks :)

Comment: Result 01 still needs some tweaking. Result includes unwanted rows: unique pair of `Name` and `Addr` and also rows if there's another row with identic `Name`. In this case `ID`s are different and `Addr` is different.

Comment: @kaptah - click the link and look at all the queries and all the results

Comment: For some reason your alternatives for 1st Result gave me different result. Or are they just differently ordered? 2nd query gave the result i need.   `MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Addr)   AS MinID,
        MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Addr)   AS MaxID`

Answer (score 1):

The [`dense_rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) window function should do the trick:

```
SELECT   ID, Name, Addr
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Addr ORDER BY ID) AS nID
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY 1, 4
```

Comment: Looks right after the OP's edit, but still fails here: `Going to create a new nID It should be copied as is OR merged if Name and Addr are identical`

Answer (score -1):

You should use RANK without partition

```
SELECT   ID, Name, Addr,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id,name,addr) AS nID
FROM     table
```

Comment: Looks right after the OP's edit, but still fails here: `Going to create a new nID It should be copied as is OR merged if Name and Addr are identical`